# How to combine LINQ group and ordering with parent and child tables?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I am trying to get a particular LINQ result set ordered and grouped.

I have two models, `Gallery` and `Media`. Galleries contain media.

`Gallery` and `Media` objects are both ordered by a key (column) called `SortOrder`.

I am trying to make a select that returns all the media in a set of galleries, but the media needs to be:

1. grouped by `GalleryId` (the gallery key)
2. the galleries ordered by `Gallery.SortOrder`
3. the media ordered by `Media.SortOrder`

So the result set would look like:

```
Gallery 1
Media 1
Media 2
Media 3
Gallery 2
Media 1
Media 2
Media 3
Gallery 3
Media 1
Media 2
Media 3
```

I currently have:

```
var EventGalleries = from g in db.Galleries
                     where g.EventId == id
                     orderby g.SortOrder
                     select g.GalleryId;

var EventMedia = from m in db.Media
                 where EventGalleries.Contains(m.GalleryId)
                 orderby m.SortOrder ascending
                 select m;
```

So now I need to reorder or group the `EventMedia` list by the `EventGalleries.SortOrder` property.

The `EventGalleries` array is already in the proper order, I'm just now sure if the `EventMedia` will be ordered/grouped properly in this manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try doing this in one query using [`Join`](http://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.linq.enumerable.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx&ei=Qs6oUrOPCcmO7QbS8YHwDQ&usg=AFQjCNHXL8_kg-gQjbPKqokTD3sePKggNA&bvm=bv.57799294,d.bGQ) and [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb534501%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var result = db.Media
    .OrderBy(m => m.SortOrder)
    .GroupBy(m => m.GalleryId)
    .Join(
        db.Galleries, 
        group => group.Key,
        g => g.GalleryId,
        (group, g) => new { Gallery = g, Media = group })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Gallery.SortOrder);
```

Here is a [working demo](http://ideone.com/oRULZe).

Comment: Just to note, the above only works when you can guarantee all galleries have at least 1 media. If there is a gallery `g3` with no media, `g3` is missing from the output. see fork of working demo. http://ideone.com/RWgaxt

Answer (score 1):

Try this,it will give you exactly what you want :

```
var items = (from g in db.Galleries
                  group g by g.GalleryId into k
                     orderby g.SortOrder
                         select new
                         {
                             Gallery = k.Key,
                             Medias = (from m in db.Media
                                       where m.GalleryId == k.Key
                                       orderby m.SortOrder
                                       select m).ToList()
                         });

            foreach (var g in items)
            {
                Console.Writeline(g.Gallery);
                foreach (var m in g.Medias)
                {
                    // write your media properties here
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Gallery` has a `Media` property that lists its `Media` children, you can write a simple iterator method:

```
IEnumerable<object> GetGalleriesAndMedia(int eventId)
{
    foreach (var gallery in from g in db.Galleries
                            where g.EventId == eventId
                            orderby g.SortOrder
                            select g)
    {
        yield return gallery;
        foreach (var media in gallery.Media.OrderBy(m => m.SortOrder))
            yield return media;
    }
}
```

If you don't have such a property, you can look it up manually:

```
IEnumerable<object> GetGalleriesAndMedia(int eventId)
{
    var eventGalleries = (from g in db.Galleries
                         where g.EventId == eventId
                         orderby g.SortOrder
                         select g).ToList();
    var eventGalleryIds = eventGalleries.Select(x => x.GalleryId).ToList();
    var eventMedia = (from m in db.Media
                      where eventGalleryIds.Contains(m.GalleryId)                          
                      orderby m.SortOrder ascending 
                      select m).ToLookup(x => x.GalleryId);
    foreach (var gallery in eventGalleries)
    {
        yield return gallery;
        foreach (var media in eventMedia[gallery.GalleryId].OrderBy(m => m.SortOrder))
            yield return media;
    }
}
```

Either way, you'll get a list of your `Gallery`s and `Media`:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, GetGalleriesAndMedia(1)));
// outputs
```

```
Gallery 1
Media 1
Media 2
Media 3
Gallery 2
Media 1
Media 2
Media 3
Gallery 3
Media 1
Media 2
Media 3
```